# Extract a Path from a server log String using regular expressions in Scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have a few logs like below

```
endeavor.fujitsu.co.jp - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /images/ HTTP/1.0" 200 17688                                   
ad13-022.compuserve.com - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /history/gemini/gemini-spacecraft.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 651       
pm2-15.magicnet.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1713                        
204.239.199.40 - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:16 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-71/images/KSC-95EC-0613.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 45970  
pm1-4.tricon.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:17 -0400] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 669                        
scorpio.digex.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:19 -0400] "GET /history/mercury/mr-3/mr-3.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1124
```

I need to extract the paths from the above logs. Here is the code that I tried

```
val pattern = "\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+HTTP".r
val match = pattern.findFirstIn(log)
```

Here is the output that I got.

```
/images/ HTTP
/history/gemini/gemini-spacecraft.txt HTTP
/images/launch-logo.gif HTTP
/shuttle/missions/sts-71/images/KSC-95EC-0613.gif HTTP
/images/WORLD-logosmall.gif HTTP
/history/mercury/mr-3/mr-3.html HTTP
```

How do I get rid of HTTP in the above paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're match is in first capturing group,

Alternatively you can use positive lookahead

```
\\s+[^\\s]+(?=\\s+HTTP)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RuQwpH/2/)

[image]

Comment: @MonkeyZeus there are lots of tools "regex visualizers" one such is [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/)

Comment: Why would you use a positive lookahead instead of matching it if you are using the captured group?

Comment: @Thefourthbird pardon my ignorance, fixed

Comment: I apologize if my comment seemed a bit blunt, what I meant was that you could also  match it instead as a positive comment.

Comment: @CodeManiac Here is one log for which I didn't get any path. columbia.acc.brad.ac.uk - - [10/Jul/1995:00:52:36 -0400] "GET /ksc.html" 200 7067 . How do I handle such logs?

Answer (score 0):

Your match is in the first capturing group `()` which you might shorten to:

```
\s(\S+)\s+HTTP
```

In Scala

```
val pattern = "\\s(\\S+)\\s+HTTP".r
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CR50py/1)

You might get the logs using findAllIn:

```
val pattern = "\\s(\\S+)\\s+HTTP".r
val strings = List(
  """endeavor.fujitsu.co.jp - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /images/ HTTP/1.0" 200 17688                                   """,
  """ad13-022.compuserve.com - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /history/gemini/gemini-spacecraft.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 651       """,
  """pm2-15.magicnet.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:15 -0400] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1713                        """,
  """204.239.199.40 - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:16 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-71/images/KSC-95EC-0613.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 45970  """,
  """pm1-4.tricon.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:17 -0400] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 669                        """,
  """scorpio.digex.net - - [10/Jul/1995:00:00:19 -0400] "GET /history/mercury/mr-3/mr-3.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1124"""
)

strings.foreach { log =>
  val m = pattern.findAllIn(log).group(1)
  println(m)
}
```

Result

```
/images/
/history/gemini/gemini-spacecraft.txt
/images/launch-logo.gif
/shuttle/missions/sts-71/images/KSC-95EC-0613.gif
/images/WORLD-logosmall.gif
/history/mercury/mr-3/mr-3.html
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/e9WvGE)

To also match this line from the comment:

> columbia.acc.brad.ac.uk - - [10/Jul/1995:00:52:36 -0400] "GET
>   /ksc.html" 200 7067

You might use:

```
\S+ (/(?:[^/\s]+/)*[^\s"]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY5okh/1)

Comment: How do I get a match out of this log --> columbia.acc.brad.ac.uk - - [10/Jul/1995:00:52:36 -0400] "GET /ksc.html" 200 7067

Comment: @Vanitha You could use for example `\S+ (/(?:[^/\s]+/)*[^\s"]+)` https://regex101.com/r/fY5okh/1

Comment: @Vanitha I have added that example to my answer.

Comment: I tried doing it and it gave me an exception. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available

Comment: Here is the code that I tried: val pattern = """\S+ (/(?:[^/\s]+/)*[^\s"]+)""".r
    val log = """columbia.acc.brad.ac.uk - - [10/Jul/1995:00:52:36 -0400] "GET /ksc.html" 200 7067"""
    val match1 = pattern.findAllIn(log).group(1)
    println(match1)

Comment: @Vanitha If I run it I get no exception. See https://ideone.com/K1WwDD So you run only that code, nothing else?